# Is $\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(x-1)}{x(x-1)}\,dx$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Does given integral

> $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(x-1)}{x(x-1)}\,dx$$

converge? If it is convergent can we evaluate it's value?

Comment: This integral diverges, but curiously enough both the related integrals $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x(x-1)} $ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x-1)}{x^2} $ converge and they can also be evaluated in closed form.

Comment: Can you please give their values?

Comment: $\pi^2 / 6$ and $0$, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider 
$$
\int_1^2 \frac{\log (x-1)}{x(x-1)}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\log u}{(1+u)u}du \sim \int_0^1 \frac{\log u}{u}du,
$$
which is divergent, since $$\frac{d}{du} \frac12 \log^2 u = \frac{\log u}{u}.$$ Hence the whole integral is divergent. By the way, the integral "at infinity" converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\log(u)-\log(1-u)}{u}\,dx = \int^1_0\frac{\log(u)}{u}\,du+\zeta(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Let $t=\log(x-1)$. Then $x=1+e^t$